# How can I force a site to scale to fix for mobile (Iphone android..)

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, viewport

When I load my site in an iphone it doesn't scale down.  All I see is the top-left most couple hundred sqare pixels.  I am new to mobile optimization, but I feel like most pages scroll to fit automatically, and most questions seem to be for the opposite scenario that I am having (force phone *not* to scale down).

I would want the whole page width to be visable and to make it so the user would have to zoom in to read the text.

I have tried with and without the following code in the head, but with no apparent effect.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!--  I Also tried: -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I've been using http://iphonetester.com/ to test...

Comment: Instead of "make it so the user would have to zoom in to read the text" do you mean "make it so the user would NOT have to zoom in to read the text"?

Comment: @Doug: nope. I want(ed) the page to render on the phone fully zoomed out, so its full 1024px width would be on the screen without scrolling. This site was NOT meant to be responsive or otherwise clever. Not ideal perhaps, but this makes the site look attractive on a phone, with all the major components in view. Users are pretty good at zooming so I let them.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

It seemed like you should ignore most of the viewport properties and just set user-scalable to "yes". It's working on my iphone now.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

Edit:: The mobile tester site doesn't allow scaling, so it just gives scrollbars. With an actual phone this works.

Answer (score 4):

try to use different css and switch them (server side) based on the client settings. For example the iPhone will identity himself like:

```
 HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) 
 AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3
```

Depending on what scripting language you have available on the server side, you could change the css.

[Here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/detect_apple_iphone_user_web_site_server.html) is an example.

Comment: I agree that this is the best way to approach the problem, but I am not prepared to create an entirely new set of styles for mobile.  I know I have seen pages on the phone without mobile-specific css that display the full page width (zoomed out) on mobile.  Also, would this approach make it so I have to create smaller images for all the headers, and any other wide graphics?

Answer (score 2):

The viewport tag controls what part of the page is going to be shown initially, but the page itself should still be designed for a 320x460 screen size to be shown on the iPhone without zooming.  If you don't want to modify the structure of the page, viewport gives you control over how the page is initially shown.

Comment: So the viewport meta tag is the right approach to this problem?  I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">` but this doesn't seem to effect anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `width=1024`, just put in

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

And, clear out your phone's browser cache. Might even have to turn off & back on afterwards.

Comment: That looks quite similar to the code I put in the Question that did *not* work. Unless the `.0` does something....
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`