# Page displayed cut off in mobile

Tags: html, mobile, viewport

when this page is displayed in a mobile browser, its not scaling and its cut. Its was not supposed to be a responsive website, but at least the user should be able to zoom it in a mobile browser.
I tried to configure the meta viewport, but nothing seams wrong. What should I do?

http://www.milu.jp/lp/kjcouple.php

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found another solution reading this article:

[How can I force a site to scale to fix for mobile (Iphone android..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154505/how-can-i-force-a-site-to-scale-to-fix-for-mobile-iphone-android)

"It seemed like you should ignore most of the viewport properties and just set user-scalable to "yes". It's working on my iphone now."

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the div's name below. Please check

Go through this article - 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

You have to edit the following

1. div class="twc" - Make its width: auto
2. div class="tweet" - Make its width: auto / left: -25px;
3. div id="tokucho" - width: auto;
4. div id="tokucho" - for the 3 div's - left, center and right, you have to use media queries and on specific screen sizes you have to set their width as 100%.
5. Also for div id="mainWraper" - you have to keep all the width as 100% on specific screen sizes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it, so should I edit the "body" with what you told me?

Comment: You have to edit all the styling (int your css file) related to divs inside the body that i have mentioned. If you find this solution useful, please mark my solution as accepted. Thanks

Comment: I am not trying to make it responsive, just scale on a mobile broser, like this site: milu.jp

Comment: So the user have to zoom in to see.

Comment: Oh. Thats great then!

Comment: Actually, adding your suggestions helped me fixing some display problems!